# Can a generic type implement multiple abstract classes?

Tags: dart

I want to create a method with a generic type that implements two different abstract classes

```
List<T> myMethod<T implements A, B>(
```

It seems this is not allowed by the compiler and the `extends` keyword only acknowledges the first class, is there an alternative way to achieve this?  If feels like this should be possible.

Comment: The best way to achieve this is to use a general superclass which extends/implements all needed abstract classes

Comment: ok, yes, I suppose that isn't such a bad solution

Comment: I posted my answer with an example @orangesherbert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer you as short as possible, yes this is possible, and no not in the way you want it to be.

**Possible solution:**
The most direct and most simple way would be to make a general superclass which then extends/implements the number of abstract (or interface) classes that you want to support/use.

Example for your case:

`List<T> myMethod<T implements A, B>`

A possible solution would be:

> The following example is pseudo-code.

```
interface A {
}

interface B {
}

abstract class C implements A, B {
}

class Generic {

   <T extends C> List<T> myMethod(T list){
     // ...
   }

}
```

*Note:* If you do not want to make use of an abstract class, you could make an interface (such as `List`) which is then used in every implementation. Instead of generics, you can (but are not required to) then just directly use this as your argument type `List<InterfaceClass>`. However, you can still use generics in this case, if you want to use type parameters. An example for this would then be as follows:

```
interface A {
}

class AImpl implements A {
}

class Generic {

    public void init(){
        myMethod(List.of(new AImpl()));
    }

     // You don't have to make use of Type parameters!
     <T extends A> List<T> myMethod(List<T> list){
         //...
     }
}
```

Comment: For the record, the question asks about #dart, and this answer is using Java syntax as pseudo-code. The answer is the same for Dart, though: You cannot have more than one type as a super-bound on a type variable. If you need two constraints, you need to give those two a name, as a new interface type, and require all accepted types to implement that combined interace.